# Site title shows page name in WP

Tags: wordpress, header

I have a problem with my own Wordpress Theme.

I need the site title to only be "Proair Luftbehandling", without the name of the page before that. Remove the "START|".

It works on the page called "Referenser" but not the other three pages.
 Now i have this in my header

```
<title> <?php bloginfo('name');?> </title>
```

http://webso.se/wordpress/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title tags show both Pagename (Start, Om Oss, etc) and Blogname (Proair...). The last part is generated by `bloginfo('name')`. The first part by presumably an SEO plugin you have installed. To remove the Start part of the homepage, you must remove the page title. Or maybe your plugin has a special setting for the homepage.

By the way, you are inserting the `<title>` tag in your header in a way that is deprecated. You may want to [read this in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag).

Comment: Sry for late answer, but thanks! It was my plugin for SEO

I will check that last thing out, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove "START|" with jQuery. Just add this code before end of body tag:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('title').html($('title').html().replace("START | ",""));
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<title> <?php echo str_replace( "START | ", "", get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?> </title>
```

Good luck